# A weaker version of the Andrica's conjecture

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, prime-gaps

Andrica's conjecture states that: For every pair of consecutive prime numbers $p_{k}$ and $p_{k+1}$, we have :

$$\sqrt{p_{k+1}}-\sqrt{p_{k}}<1\quad\quad \color{#2d0}{\text{(1.)}}$$

I know that is statement is not yet proved. But I am asking on a **weaker** version:

Show that inequality $\color{#2d0}{\text{(1.)}}$ holds true for infinitely many indices $k$.

This is possible for the Legendre conjecture. See: [Show that there exist infinitely many indices $k$ such that the intervals $[k^2,(k+1)^2]$ contain at least one prime number](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3332677/show-that-there-exist-infinitely-many-indices-k-such-that-the-intervals-k2)

Comment: It's easy to show that [it's true on average](https://rtybase.blogspot.com/2012/11/tackling-andricas-conjecture-part-2.html)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's easy to show that ([given](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_number_theorem#Approximations_for_the_nth_prime_number) $p_n \sim n\ln{n}$)
$$\color{red}{\frac{\sum\limits_{k=2}^n\left(\sqrt{p_k}-\sqrt{p_{k-1}}\right)}{n-1}}=
\frac{\sqrt{p_n}-\sqrt{p_{1}}}{n-1}=\\
\frac{\sqrt{p_n}}{n-1}-\frac{\sqrt{p_{1}}}{n-1}=\\
\sqrt{\frac{p_n}{n\ln{n}}\cdot\frac{n\ln{n}}{({n-1)^2}}}-\frac{\sqrt{p_{1}}}{n-1}\sim \\
\sqrt{\frac{n\ln{n}}{({n-1)^2}}}\color{red}{\to 0}, n\to\infty$$
And now, if we assume that $\sqrt{p_k}-\sqrt{p_{k-1}}<1$ for a finite number of $k$'s, say $K$, then from some $n$ onwards
$$\color{blue}{\frac{\sum\limits_{k=2}^n\left(\sqrt{p_k}-\sqrt{p_{k-1}}\right)}{n-1}}=\\
\frac{\sum\limits_{\sqrt{p_k}-\sqrt{p_{k-1}}\geq1}\left(\sqrt{p_k}-\sqrt{p_{k-1}}\right)}{n-1}+
\frac{\sum\limits_{\sqrt{p_k}-\sqrt{p_{k-1}}<1}\left(\sqrt{p_k}-\sqrt{p_{k-1}}\right)}{n-1}\geq\\
\frac{n-K}{n-1}+
\frac{\sum\limits_{\sqrt{p_k}-\sqrt{p_{k-1}}<1}\left(\sqrt{p_k}-\sqrt{p_{k-1}}\right)}{n-1}\sim \frac{n-K}{n-1}\color{blue}{\to1}, n\to\infty$$
which contradicts the previous limit.

Answer (score 7):

Assuming the contrary it follows (induction) that there exists $A$ such that  $\sqrt{p_k}> k-A$ for all $k$ and this would imply 
$\sum \frac{1}{p_k} < \infty$, contradiction.

Answer (score 4):

Assume that

$$\sqrt{p_{k+1}} - \sqrt{p_{k}} \lt 1 \tag{1}\label{eq1A}$$

only holds for a finite number of indices $k$. Thus, there's some integer $n_0$ where for *all* $k \ge n_0$ you have

$$\sqrt{p_{k+1}} - \sqrt{p_{k}} \ge 1 \tag{2}\label{eq2A}$$

Move $\sqrt{p_{k}}$ to the right side and, since they're both positive quantities, square both sides, and make some other adjustments to get

$$\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
\sqrt{p_{k+1}} & \ge \sqrt{p_{k}} + 1 \\
p_{k+1} & \ge p_{k} + 2\sqrt{p_{k}} + 1 \\
p_{k+1} - p_{k} & \ge 2\sqrt{p_{k}} + 1
\end{aligned}\end{equation}\tag{3}\label{eq3A}$$

However, the [Prime Number Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_number_theorem) states the difference between consecutive primes is, asymptotically on average, the natural logarithm of the number (e.g., Wikipedia's "Prime Gap" page's [Upper bounds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_gap#Upper_bounds) section's second paragraph explicitly says "The prime number theorem, proven in 1896, says that the average length of the gap between a prime $p$ and the next prime will asymptotically approach $\ln(p)$ for sufficiently large primes"). Thus, you get

$$p_{k+1} - p_{k} \sim \ln(p_{k}) \tag{4}\label{eq4A}$$

However, for even fairly small primes, you have $2\sqrt{p_{k}} + 1 \gg \ln(p_{k})$. You can't have \eqref{eq3A} holding for *all* $k \ge n_0$ when the average value is so much less, so the original assumption of finiteness must be incorrect.

Another way to see this is sum the inequalities in \eqref{eq3A} to some $N - 1 \gg n_0$ to get

$$\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
\sum_{k=n_0}^{N-1}(p_{k+1} - p_{k}) & \ge \sum_{k=n_0}^{N-1}(2\sqrt{p_{k}} + 1) \\
p_{N} - p_{n_0} & \ge \sum_{k=n_0}^{N-1}(2\sqrt{p_{k}} + 1)
\end{aligned}\end{equation}\tag{5}\label{eq5A}$$

However, the PNT says $p_{N} \sim N\ln(N)$, which is *much* less than the right hand side of \eqref{eq5A}. As such, the original assumption must be wrong and, thus, there are an infinite number of indices $k$ for which \eqref{eq1A} holds.

Comment: Can we do the same analysis with the Brocard's Conjecture.

Comment: @Germany If you mean showing that Brocard's Conjecture holds for infinitely many prime indices, then I believe you can do a similar type of analysis to show this, but I haven't thought about it carefully.

Comment: Which part of PNT states that $p_{k+1}-p_k\sim \ln{p_k}$? This would solve Andrica's conjecture straightaway! Because $\sqrt{p_{k+1}}-\sqrt{p_k}<\frac{C\ln{p_k}}{2\sqrt{p_{k-1}}}\to0$ ...

Comment: @rtybase In the PNT Wikipedia article's $2$nd paragraph, it says "... for large enough $N$, the probability that a random integer not greater than $N$ is prime is very close to $1 / \log(N)$". Thus, the next prime would occur at about $\log(N)$ distance. Also, the Wikipedia's "Prime Gap" page's [Upper bounds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_gap#Upper_bounds) section's $2$nd paragraph explicitly says "The prime number theorem, proven in 1896, says that the average length of the gap between a prime $p$ and the next prime will asymptotically approach $\ln(p)$ for sufficiently large primes".

Comment: @JohnOmielan I know those articles by heart :) ... the best result for now is $p_{k+1}-p_k<p_{k}^{\theta}$, but not $\log{p_k}$.

Comment: @rtybase I'm not considering any individual value specifically but, instead, that my contradiction involves $p_{k+1} - p_{k} \ge 2\sqrt{p_k} + 1$ for *all* $k$ larger than some $n_0$. This is incompatible with the differences between consecutive primes being, on average, the logarithm of those primes. For example, for a very large $N$, $\sum_{k = n_0}^{N}(p_{k+1} - p{k}) = p_{N} - p_{n_0}$. However, it would be larger than $\sum_{k = n_0}^{N}(2\sqrt{p_{k}} + 1)$, which would be much larger than the sum of the average prime gaps according to the PNT &, thus, $P_N$ would be much too large.

Comment: @JohnOmielan sounds like you need to fix the answer, to point at the averages.

Comment: @rtybase I added some more details to try to make it more clear for everybody.